# Why my ERC20 (EXOToken) deployed contract not display properly in etherscan?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

Today I have deploy EXOToken [smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe58e751aba3b9406367b5f3cbc39c2fa9b519789) on Ethereum mainnet, [tx is here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xba8b3246522b8d15a77b218c690606aa735ac2f4c39f8af1c4777dc7d9e5d09c)

But if look at this link, you can see,  that it's not look  like properly ERC20 smartcontract: there are no Token Contract capltion in Contract Overview section. And when I try  see through token veiew:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xe58e751aba3b9406367b5f3cbc39c2fa9b519789
it seems like etherscan don't recognize decimals (0 vs 18),  but if go to the ReadContarct  link one  can see,  that decimals=18.
Then I have deploy exactly same code  on Rinkeby net.  There is all OK in both view:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0093f46784ab6b2c4de7985bb5dfa6cb5467c7f9
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x0093f46784ab6b2c4de7985bb5dfa6cb5467c7f9
So on Rinkeby this smartcontract display as properly ERC20. Hence, all is ok with source code.
I think it can be connected with the fact that  some times ago  I have already deployd  smartcontract with same name (EXOLOVER) and Symbol (EXO) on mainnet. That is it:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xe52dc28df14d370436c25148b16e78d41b195e99
It`s not properly contract and it's never be work.
So What can I do  for properly  view  of  my contracr as soon as possible, becouse  ICO will start soon?

Comment: Your third link links to a different URL from what it says